# elixir upload file to google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, elixir

I am following instructions from google drive api [google drive upload file api](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads#multipart) 
Here is my request body

```
multipart_request_body = 
--1234567
Content-Type: application/json


{ name: "text.csv", mimeType: "text/csv"}
--1234567
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: text/comma-separated-values
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary


id,promo\n1,asdadas
--1234567--
```

and header

```
headers = [{"Content-Type", "multipart/related; boundary=1234567"},
           {"Content-Length", byte_size(multipart_request_body)},
           {"Authorization","Bearer #{access_token}"}]`
```

and url

```
api_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart"
```

I am using `HTTPoison` to make a post request:

```
response = HTTPoison.post!(api_url,multipart_request_body, headers)
```

and i'm getting `status_code: 200` and the returned metadata is `%{"id" => "0B6Xd6TBQkqUPM0s4TEY5SGRXcU0", "kind" => "drive#file",
  "mimeType" => "text/csv", "name" => "text.csv"}`

But when i check my google drive, the file never exists and i cannot get the file by using the return `id`.

I have been stucked here for many hours, can anyone help what is wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure the access_token is of the same account that you're checking the Google Drive account of?

Comment: try doing a files.list after you upload it.  The API says its uploaded.  and its giving you a file id of the file that was uploaded.    Any chance this is a service account you are using and your uploading to the service accounts drive account.

Comment: @DaImTo yeah, i am using service account to upload the file, how do i view the service account drive account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service accounts are not you.  Think of service accounts as a dummy user. It has its own drive account, Google calendar account and probably a bunch more.

When you upload to a service account you are uploading to the service accounts Google drive account.  There is no way to access the service accounts drive account graphically though for example the Google drive website.

Now you have a few options.

1. Share a folder on your google drive account with the service account and upload to that by setting the parent id of the file you are uploading to the id of the folder on your account.  Issues with this include permissions, the service account will own the file and have to upadate the permissions on the file to give your person a google account access to it.
2. have the service account create a directory on its account and share that with your personal google account.   Issues with this also are permissions on the file in question.  Just because your personal account has access to the directory when files are added to it they must be patched to give you access this is not something that is done automcatcly.  So it is possible to have access to a directory but not access to the files that have been uploaded into the directory.
3. create your own graphical interface for the service account. Using file.list to return a list of files currently on the drive account.

My tutorial on service accounts [Google Developer console service account](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/) which goes into depth on how service accounts work.